# Cannot login to Oracle11g with System username

Tags: oracle

I just installed Oracle 11g into my machine.
I was about to shut down a database instance, and Oracle asked me for username and password, I provided the credentials I used to login into the web system, and it said that the credentials were wrong.

I googled how to change credentials, so I logged in into SQL Plus and did the following:

```
   ALTER USER sys IDENTIFIED BY "my_new_password";
```

then I tried to shut down the database instance logging in with the user `sys` and the new password and oracle still complaint about wrong credentials. Then I logged off, and when I tried to log in with my username and password they didn't work. I tried to login with sys and the new password and it didn't work, and now I completely out of the database management web site, and I can't do anything.

I do not know where to go from here, I'm working in a Windows 7 Machine.

Comment: Are you trying to login as "sys" or "system"?  They are different.  Here's a posting that explains the difference between the two: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/405/what-is-the-difference-between-sys-and-system-accounts-in-oracle-databases

Comment: your sys password is case sensitive as you mentioned in " ". Use my_new_password in lower case letters.

Comment: Are you talking about shutting down Oracle via Enterprise Manager (the web-based GUI)?  Or via a command-line?  Enterprise Manager will request operating system credentials (on Windows, a Windows username & password that is in the `ORA_DBA` group) in order to start and stop certain services.  A command-line tool will not (since, after all, you're using your operating system privileges inherently in that environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, checked ORA_DBA group and it was OK, reconnected through command line using SYS account -> worked, then reconnected to webapp -> worked!

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned you were on a Windows machine and a brand new DB.  A problem I've run into is the ORA_DBA group.  Windows has a habit of not allowing you to log into an Oracle DB with high level credentials if your OS account is not in the ORA_DBA group.  We found this problem when we migrated to Windows 2008.  I have no experience with Windows 7, but feel like its a safe assumption that it has a security setup similar to 2008, and this may be your problem.